# Iterative Expansion of an Equation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a method that will perform an iterative expansion of an equation that, after the second iteration, has a defined pattern.  I need to get the results for each iteration into a `List<T>`, so I need to stop at each.

The first few steps look like this:

```
Fraction step1 = whole + half;
Console.WriteLine("  1: " + step1);
Fraction step2 = whole + whole / (whole * 2 + half);
Console.WriteLine("  2: " + step2);
Fraction step3 = whole + whole / (whole * 2 + whole / (whole * 2 + half));
Console.WriteLine("  3: " + step3);
Fraction step4 = whole + whole / (whole * 2 + whole / (whole * 2 + whole / (whole * 2 + half)));
Console.WriteLine("  4: " + step4);
Fraction step5 = whole + whole / (whole * 2 + whole / (whole * 2 + whole / (whole * 2 + whole / (whole * 2 + half))));
Console.WriteLine("  5: " + step5);
```

Basically after each iteration `step >= 2`, `half` gets replaced with `whole / (whole * 2 + half)` continuing on for n-iterations.

I'm not entirely sure how to write an iterative equation like that in C#, though.

Clarifications:  There will be at least 1000 iterations.  Only step 1 doesn't follow the pattern (I guess technically step 2 doesn't as it establishes the pattern).

Comment: Are steps, whole and half are classes, of type Fraction overriding `+` and `*` operator?

Comment: @GauravMathur - `Fraction` is a struct that has appropriate overrides for + and *. `whole` is a `Fraction` that just equates to 1/1 and `half` is a `Fraction` that equates to 1/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
        List<Fraction> steps = new List<Fraction>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                half = whole / (whole * 2 + half);
            var step = whole + half;
            steps.Add(step);
            Console.WriteLine($"   {i + 1}: {step}");
        }
```

All the steps are stored in `steps` list.

Comment: Perfect - modified it a small bit for my needs, but ultimately this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!